# Which compression functions are MACs?

Tags: hash, hmac, mac, compression-function

The [original HMAC paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/kmd5.pdf) based the security proof on the fact that the compression function of the Hash is already a MAC (appropriately keyed).

How does this relate to common assumptions for compressions functions?
Is it required to show security of the Hash function?
Conversely, can a good hash function have a weak compression function which is not a MAC?

This is of course related to my question about which [compressions functions are PRFs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44706/which-compression-functions-are-prfs).